# How to read variable as a Number in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline YAML file that takes variables from the 'Variables' button as opposed to having "variables:" in the YAML file itself.

I'm trying to pass a Number to a step that requires a Number as the parameter, however the pipeline is failing to run because it's saying the value is not a valid Number.

Inside the "Variables" button, I have the variable `VersionId` with the given value `12345`.

```
extends:
  template: Directory/To/The/Template.yaml@Name
  parameters:
    projectVersionId: $(VersionId)
```

Is there a way I can explicitly state that this a number, and not a string?

I have tried using both `${{variables.VersionId}}` and `$[variables.VersionId]`

Comment: is there any specific reason why you re using variables rather than parameters ?

Comment: You can take a look of my answer.

Comment: @Thomas I don't have access to the .yml file I'm extending, it's maintained by other developers

Comment: I mean you can define a number  parameter in your own pipeline then pass this parameter to the template.

Comment: Hi Stefan, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$[ variables['VersionId'] ]`

This somewhat explains the reason why this works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that run-time variables are not yet available at the time the value pass the template parameter.

And you need to specify the value type via parameter definition:

**give_parameter.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  VersionId: 12345


extends:
  template: Directory/To/The/Template.yml
  parameters:
    projectVersionId: ${{variables.VersionId }}
```

**Directory/To/The/Template.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: projectVersionId
    type: number
    default: 1


steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: ${{ eq(parameters.projectVersionId, 12345)}}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     # Write your PowerShell commands here.
```

You can see that we pass the check step successfully:

[image]